# Running Nav2DWidget without pr2/gazebo/rviz

Tags: ros, move-base-msgs, ros-indigo, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the [Nav2DWidget](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2djs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicNav2DWidget) tutorial to work fine but my objective is to have a simple mobile base in the place of pr2. I see that the system uses a move-base action but I am not sure how to re-purpose it to work it with a simple mobile base.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295090/running-nav2dwidget-without-pr2/gazebo/rviz/) by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The move_base node provides the move base action. All of the tuning and setup can be lengthy, but there's a good ROS tutorial that goes through the basics pretty well: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup . I believe there are also several books on the subject, but I haven't read any.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0